# Exception error in PHP

Tags: jquery, cakephp

while opening a page to view my Form in my application i am getting the error
as
[Exception... "'Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #' when calling method: [nsIDOMEventListener::handleEvent]" nsresult: "0x8057001e (NS_ERROR_XPC_JS_THREW_STRING)" location: "" data: no]

i dont know why its so??? please suggest me.

i am having JQuery and Php in my page..

Comment: you should post your code ....

Comment: This one is in your javascript part, not PHP (although, of course, it may be caused by PHP code).

Answer (score 1):

This is an old FireFox bug:
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=261423

You can use autocomplete='off' to get rid of it.

Comment: how to set autocomplete='off'

Comment: i am not having any auto complete feature in this page .. Its in another page only.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to debug these kinds of problems. I guess you are using Firefox. Try using another browser's error reporting feature, I recommend Opera. If you are using AJAX services try checking your address sent data and check if your produced XML is valid.